# string format custom method extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok, so I got this awesome bit of code from another post:

```
String.prototype.format = function (values) {

    var regex = /\{([\w-]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?\}/g;

    var getValue = function (key) {
        if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return null;

        var value = values[key];
        var type = typeof value;

        return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
    };

    return this.replace(regex, function (match) {
        //match will look like {sample-match}
        //key will be 'sample-match';
        var key = match.substr(1, match.length - 2);

        var value = getValue(key);

        return value != null ? value : match;
    });
};
```

if you have a look at my json object, it looks like this:

```
{
    "Id":4019,
    "FileName":"2013-08-24 15.00.15.jpg",
    "ThumbNail":"http://d49aa22b-3476-4fac-8bef-38f53f9378f3.s3.amazonaws.com/2013-08-24 15.00.15_thumb.png",
    "DisplayName":"2013-08-24 15.00.15.jpg",
    "CompanyId":"D49AA22B-3476-4FAC-8BEF-38F53F9378F3",
    "CreatedById":"76026710-ad16-4533-b5fc-47ddd5ab415b",
    "Type":3,
    "DateCreated":"2014-02-11T18:23:07.047",
    "DateModified":"2014-02-11T23:22:31.393",
    "LanguageId":1,
    "Converted":true,
    "Status":1,
    "IsPublic":false,
    "ModifiedById":"132CD2AE-C942-40DA-897E-3D6C5DCB7963",
    "Language":null,
    "Metadata":{
        "AssetId":4019,
        "ReferenceId":"cc68d994c957c0a4",
        "Tags":null,
        "Description":null,
        "Filename":null,
        "FileSize":"1566 kB",
        "FileType":"JPEG",
        "MIMEType":"image/jpeg",
        "CreateDate":"",
        "ModifyDate":"2013:08:24 15:00:15",
        "AddedDate":null,
        "AudioBitRate":null,
        "SampleRate":null,
        "ChannelMode":null,
        "Duration":null,
        "Track":null,
        "Album":null,
        "Year":null,
        "Title":null,
        "Genre":null,
        "Band":null,
        "Composer":null,
        "Artist":null,
        "VideoFrameRate":null,
        "VideoCodec":null,
        "ImageWidth":2448,
        "ImageHeight":3264,
        "ImageSize":"2448x3264",
        "XResolution":null,
        "YResolution":null,
        "ResolutionUnit":null,
        "Orientation":null
    },
    "Company":null,
    "CreatedBy":null,
    "ModifiedBy":null,
    "Comments":null,
    "Ratings":null,
    "Categories":null,
    "Collections":null,
    "SynchronisedAssets":null
}
```

now, if I use my function like this (item is the json):

```
var rowTemplate = "<tr data-id=\"{Id}\"><td>{FileName}</td><td>{FileSize}</td><td></td><td><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-id=\"{Id}\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button></td></tr>";
var row = rowTemplate.format(item);
```

I get the output returned like this:

```
<tr data-id="4019"><td>2013-08-24 15.00.15.jpg</td><td>{FileSize}</td><td></td><td><button type="button" class="close" data-id="4019" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></td></tr>
```

The problem (if you can't already see it :D) is that I want to get the FileSize to display too, but that is in a nested JSON object **Metadata**.
Can anyone show me how to get my function to work with that?

I tried {Metadata.FileSize} but that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with changeing the regex to support dots (so `Metadata.FileSize` will match), like:

```
/\{([\w-.]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?\}/g
```

Then you'll need to find the value, for example:

```
var getValue = function (key) {
    var value = values,
        arr, type;

    if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return null;

    if (key.indexOf('.')) {
        arr = key.split('.');

        while (arr.length && value) {
            value = value[arr.shift()];
        }
    } else {
        value = val && val[key] || values[key];
    }

    type = typeof value;

    return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
};
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tdLKc/

---

Or using `reduce`, like:

```
var getValue = function (key) {
    var value = values,
        arr, type;

    if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return null;

    if (key.indexOf('.')) {
        arr = key.split('.');

        value = arr.reduce(function(a, b){
          return a[b];
        }, values);

    } else {
        value = val && val[key] || values[key];
    }
    type = typeof value;

    return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
};
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tdLKc/1/

Answer (score 1):

String.prototype.format = function (values) {

```
var regex = /\{([\w-]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?\}/g;

if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return;

var getValue = function (key) 
    {
    var i, l, value, type, referrer;

    if (key.indexOf (".")>-1)
       {
       key=key.split(".");
       l=key.length;
       referrer=values;
       for (i=0;i<l;i++)
         referrer=referrer[key[i]];
       value=referrer;
       }
    else
      value = values[key];
    type = typeof value;

    return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
};

return this.replace(regex, function (match) {
    //match will look like {sample-match}
    //key will be 'sample-match';
    var key = match.substr(1, match.length - 2);

    var value = getValue(key);

    return value != null ? value : match;
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,I define the path for it to take data correctly and more efficient.

```
var rowTemplate = "<tr data-id=\"{Id}\"><td>{FileName}</td><td>{Metadata.FileSize}</td><td></td><td><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-id=\"{Id}\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button></td></tr>";
```

and edit a litle in format :

```
String.prototype.format = function (values) {

var regex = /\{([\w-.]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?\}/g ;

var getValue = function (key) {
    if (values == null || typeof values === 'undefined') return null;

    var keydata = key.split('.');
    var  data, type
        ,num =  keydata.length;        


    while(keydata.length){
        value = (num == keydata.length) 
        ? values[keydata.shift()] 
        : value[keydata.shift()];            
    }       
        type = typeof value;

    return type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? value : null;
  };

return this.replace(regex, function (match) {
    //match will look like {sample-match}        
    //key will be 'sample-match';
    console.log('match',match);
    var key = match.substr(1, match.length - 2);

    var value = getValue(key);

    return value != null ? value : match;
  });
};
```

Cause in an object, you may have same key name, and the only way help you to avoid it is design object format does not have any attrs's name is the same. It could become nightmare with some format such as : { a : {b :{'FileSize': 'hell year'}}} 
.In your JSON I see 2 attrs  have the same name but you made it different by lowercase a character (File**N**ame and File**n**ame), you did it to avoid wrong attrs, isn't it?

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scX3f/1/
sorry for my terrible English if it bother you :).